# OpenLayers 3: Can I set a default "error tile" for when a tile is not available?

Tags: openlayers, tiles

Many of my map layers are zoomable to zoom level 21, but one of my basemaps is only zoomable to 18. When I zoom past this level with that particular basemap activated, the background goes white.

I'd like to indicate to my user that this is expected behavior and that there's just no data for that zoom level. I'd like to do this by inserting a tile similar to Google Maps's "no data" tile.

Can I set a default error tile in OpenLayers 3?

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have added to your map an OSM layer.
you have to asign the 'tileloaderror' listener to the source of your tile layer. But this would not indicate whether thats a problem of the zoom level or for example a network error. It is just indicating that layer could not be loaded.

**Check the code**

```
osmLayer.getSource().on('tileloaderror', function(event) {
//replace with your custom action        
alert("could not load tile layer");
 });
```

you may find the documentation API [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.source.TileEvent.html#event:tileloaderror). Though it doesnt eplain much